# Usage of "lest"

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence with "lest" grammatical?

> "You shouldn't swear lest you'll look like a hypocrite."

Comment: Ask Shakespeare.

Comment: LEST is not frequently used. It works like, You should study, lest you stand to lose the opportunities.
You should study, if not you stand to lose the opportunities.
You should study so that you should not stand to lose the opportunities

Comment: In your example, it should be, 'You shouldn't swear, if not you look like a hypocrite/ You shouldn't swear, so that you shouldn't  look like a hypocrite.

Comment: No it isn’t correct.  It should be “... lest you look like a ...” not “you will look”

Comment: The quoted line is archaic in style.  It was "correct" in its time.

Comment: My nearest dictionary says "lest" is formal. (It doesn't say "archaic".) It also says that "lest" is one of the few words that still require the subjunctive. So your example should read "lest you look" (as Jim already pointed out in his comment).

Comment: @Andreas Blass _This particular example_ is certainly archaic-to-obsolescent in style; others may be less so.  CED has a blanket 'literary' caveat. Dictionaries are often too broad-brush.

Comment: It would help to know where you found this sentence.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/awtgvh/lesson_learned_dont_colonize_gaia_worlds_lest/

Comment: https://ownquotes.com/quote/170968

Comment: https://grammargang.com/parts-of-speech/what-is-a-conjunction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lest is generally followed by a verb clause, and the construction as a whole creates a subjunctive mood (A hypothetical).

No auxiliary verbs like "will", "would" etc are used following "lest", although "should" can be used in many cases.

The grammatical version, in this case, is either

- You shouldn't swear lest you look like a hypocrite
- You shouldn't swear lest you should look like a hypocrite

[Props to Edwin for reminding me of the grammaticality of "Should"]

Comment: Yes, that is grammatical as well. I just gave him the version closest to the one he supplied.

Comment: @YosefBaskin The answer to "Is this grammatical?" is quite obviously implied when offering a correction is it not?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Incorporated

Comment: Note that if "should" is grammatical then "will" or "would" would be as well.

Comment: I plead ignorance on why it is the case, but no auxiliary verb apart from "should" is grammatical. If you know of any instance where "will" or "would" is used in a published work, I'll gladly correct it.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace "lest" with "so that", provided that you also negate the verb in the following clause.

The main clause indicates some action, and the clause introduced by "lest" indicates the purpose of that action, namely that the stated thing does *not* happen.

The OP's sentence is

1. You shouldn't swear lest you'll look like a hypocrite.

Now to me, "lest" does *not* suit that sentence. As it stands, it means

2. You shouldn't swear so that you won't look like a hypocrite.

But (if I understand the OP correctly) the subsidiary clause here describes a *consequence* of *swearing*. One way to say what the OP means is

3. You shouldn't swear or you'll look like a hypocrite.

For a similar sentence which uses "lest", I'd need an undesirable consequence, where the purpose of not swearing is to avoid this. Perhaps the following?

4. I took care not to swear lest the other people would think me rude.